# Google cloud functions - cannot read property 'getApplicationDefault'

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow, google-api-nodejs-client

I have deployed a cloud function to invoke a dataflow pipeline template and trying to trigger the function by placing the file in cloud storage bucket.

As node.js prerequisite I have done,

```
npm init
npm install --save googleapis
```

Index.js

```
const google = require('googleapis');

exports.goWithTheDataFlow = function(event, callback) {
 const file = event.data;



   google.auth.getApplicationDefault(function (err, authClient, projectId) {
     if (err) {
       throw err;
     }

 console.log(projectId);
     if (authClient.createScopedRequired && authClient.createScopedRequired()) {
       authClient = authClient.createScoped([
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
       ]);
     }

     const dataflow = google.dataflow({ version: 'v1b3', auth: authClient });
            console.log(`gs://${file.bucket}/${file.name}`);
     dataflow.projects.templates.create({
       projectId: projectId,
       resource: {
         parameters: {
           inputFile: `gs://${file.bucket}/${file.name}`

         },
         jobName: 'cloud-fn-dataflow-test',
         gcsPath: 'gs://jaison/templates/ApacheBeamTemplate'
       }
     }, function(err, response) {
       if (err) {
         console.error("problem running dataflow template, error was: ", err);
       }
       console.log("Dataflow template response: ", response);
       callback();
     });

   });

 callback();
};
```

Command used to deploy cloud function:

```
gcloud beta functions deploy goWithTheDataFlow --stage-bucket cf100stage --trigger-bucket cf100
```

Dataflow(Apache beam):
I was able to execute the dataflow template from console and below is the path of the template,

```
'gs://jaison/templates/ApacheBeamTemplate'
```

Function crashes with below error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getApplicationDefault' of undefined
>   at exports.goWithTheDataFlow (/user_code/index.js:11:17) at
>   /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:695:16 at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:660:9 at
>   _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7) at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)

Looks like I am missing libraries. Not sure how to fix this. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My cloud function works with below changes,

1.Setting up GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to service account json file

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/of/svc/json/file.json"
```

2.index.js

```
var {google} = require('googleapis');

exports.TriggerBeam = (event, callback) => {


const file = event.data;
  const context = event.context;

  console.log(`Event ${context.eventId}`);
  console.log(`  Event Type: ${context.eventType}`);
  console.log(`  Bucket: ${file.bucket}`);
  console.log(`  File: ${file.name}`);
  console.log(`  Metageneration: ${file.metageneration}`);
  console.log(`  Created: ${file.timeCreated}`);
  console.log(`  Updated: ${file.updated}`);

  google.auth.getApplicationDefault(function (err, authClient, projectId) {
     if (err) {
       throw err;
     }

 console.log(projectId);

 const dataflow = google.dataflow({ version: 'v1b3', auth: authClient });
        console.log(`gs://${file.bucket}/${file.name}`);
 dataflow.projects.templates.create({
   projectId: projectId,
   resource: {
     parameters: {
       inputFile: `gs://${file.bucket}/${file.name}`

     },
     jobName: 'cloud-fn-beam-test',
     gcsPath: 'gs://jaison/templates/ApacheBeamTemplate'
   }
 }, function(err, response) {
   if (err) {
     console.error("problem running dataflow template, error was: ", err);
   }
   console.log("Dataflow template response: ", response);
   callback();
 });

   });

 callback();
};
```

Comment: No this doesn't work for me. Is that just export added while deploying the function using gcloud? What if I install using the UI?

Comment: Not just the export statement. you have to modify your index.js file too.

Comment: Hi @Vetri, is this working still for you? porjectId comes undefined to me and if I set it explicitly I get a TypeError: authClient.request is not a function both in the emulator and production

Comment: @garcianavalon Yes. It works for me. This code depends on default credentials. Please check your configuration.

Comment: @Vetri thanks for your answer! I managed to make my function work after fixing a couple of issues. For the record, I didn't need to export the env variable if cloud function emulator is correctly configured